# What does "Can't determine Firebase Database URL" error mean in heroku when I try to launch my application?

Tags: firebase, heroku, algolia

I just finish my first react app, and in this app, there is a search bar generated by Algolia service. So, I need to create an app for record every change in my databse (I use Firebase). So I created this application by following [this tutorial](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/sending-and-managing-data/send-and-update-your-data/tutorials/firebase-algolia/) proposed by Algolia. In local, when i run my app, everything work fine. But I need to deploy this app on Heroku, and after finishing uploading to Heroku, i use the command line "heroku open" but I have an error. So I launch in my console the command line "heroku logs --tail" and I have this following analysis:

```
2019-01-19T22:39:11.633651+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user camille.demarle@gmail.com
2019-01-19T22:39:11.482216+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user camille.demarle@gmail.com
2019-01-19T22:39:11.482216+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user camille.demarle@gmail.com
2019-01-19T22:39:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user camille.demarle@gmail.com
2019-01-19T22:40:14.757634+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 8ebe9ea0 by user camille.demarle@gmail.com
2019-01-19T22:40:14.773417+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user camille.demarle@gmail.com
2019-01-19T22:40:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-01-19T22:40:30.451972+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-19T22:40:30.462980+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-01-19T22:40:30.428680+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-01-19T22:40:30.295717+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-01-19T22:40:30.291Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.  Be sure to include databaseURL option when calling firebase.initializeApp().
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302310+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:335
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302314+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new Error(message);
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302316+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302317+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302331+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.  Be sure to include databaseURL option when calling firebase.initializeApp().
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302340+00:00 app[web.1]: at fatal (/app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:335:11)
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302347+00:00 app[web.1]: at RepoManager.databaseFromApp (/app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14987:13)
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302353+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.instance.INTERNAL.registerService.Reference [as database] (/app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15526:130)
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302355+00:00 app[web.1]: at FirebaseAppImpl._getService (/app/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:138:66)
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302364+00:00 app[web.1]: at FirebaseAppImpl.(anonymous function) [as database] (/app/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:327:31)
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302366+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.serviceNamespace [as database] (/app/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:312:32)
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302368+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:12:27)
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302370+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302376+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
2019-01-19T22:40:30.302378+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
2019-01-19T22:40:35.847284+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-19T22:41:48.668846+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2019-01-19T22:41:45.297979+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user camille.demarle@gmail.com
2019-01-19T22:41:45.297979+00:00 app[api]: Set ALGOLIA_APP_ID config vars by user camille.demarle@gmail.com
2019-01-19T22:42:15.784624+00:00 app[api]: Set ALGOLIA_API_KEY config vars by user camille.demarle@gmail.com
2019-01-19T22:42:21.343612+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2019-01-19T22:42:24.278823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-01-19T22:42:24.203298+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-01-19T22:42:24.201Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.  Be sure to include databaseURL option when calling firebase.initializeApp().
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207461+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:335
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207464+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new Error(message);
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207466+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207467+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207478+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.  Be sure to include databaseURL option when calling firebase.initializeApp().
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207480+00:00 app[web.1]: at fatal (/app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:335:11)
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207482+00:00 app[web.1]: at RepoManager.databaseFromApp (/app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14987:13)
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207484+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.instance.INTERNAL.registerService.Reference [as database] (/app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15526:130)
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207485+00:00 app[web.1]: at FirebaseAppImpl._getService (/app/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:138:66)
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207487+00:00 app[web.1]: at FirebaseAppImpl.(anonymous function) [as database] (/app/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:327:31)
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207489+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.serviceNamespace [as database] (/app/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:312:32)
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207490+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:12:27)
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207492+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207494+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
2019-01-19T22:42:24.207495+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
2019-01-19T22:42:46.165385+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-01-19T22:42:45.890812+00:00 app[api]: Set ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME config vars by user camille.demarle@gmail.com
2019-01-19T22:42:57.475941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-19T22:42:57.460531+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-01-19T22:42:57.358726+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-01-19T22:42:57.356Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.  Be sure to include databaseURL option when calling firebase.initializeApp().
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365146+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:335
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365149+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new Error(message);
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365151+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365153+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365164+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.  Be sure to include databaseURL option when calling firebase.initializeApp().
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365166+00:00 app[web.1]: at fatal (/app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:335:11)
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365168+00:00 app[web.1]: at RepoManager.databaseFromApp (/app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14987:13)
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365170+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.instance.INTERNAL.registerService.Reference [as database] (/app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15526:130)
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365171+00:00 app[web.1]: at FirebaseAppImpl._getService (/app/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:138:66)
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365173+00:00 app[web.1]: at FirebaseAppImpl.(anonymous function) [as database] (/app/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:327:31)
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365175+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.serviceNamespace [as database] (/app/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:312:32)
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365177+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:12:27)
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365179+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365181+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
2019-01-19T22:42:57.365182+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
2019-01-19T22:44:19.417434+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2019-01-19T22:44:19.417597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-01-19T22:44:19.977203+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-19T22:44:19.958621+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2019-01-19T22:44:22.174368+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=immense-tundra-17222.herokuapp.com request_id=03b6ee82-8267-4695-8172-d382d14c917f fwd="176.161.115.132" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-19T22:54:22.270007+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-01-19T22:54:26.834608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2019-01-19T22:55:14.361517+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=652M(127.4%)
2019-01-19T22:55:14.361517+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2019-01-19T22:55:27.356583+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2019-01-19T22:55:27.356583+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-01-19T22:55:28.057069+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-19T22:55:28.034934+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

It seems that this comes from my connection to firebase which fails, though I have specified the path, both in my .env file and directly in Heroku by specifying variables (in doubt ...)

This is the first time for me to try upload an app in Heroku. No idea that could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be anything, but most probably the following is the reason:

Your process.ENV variables used in local environment will not work in Heroku.

In Heroku you have to set all process.ENV variables like this:

```
heroku config:set FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL='https://abcd.firebaseio.com'
```

If you have more process.ENV variables you can set all adding space at the end:

```
heroku config:set FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL='https://abcd.firebaseio.com'  FIREBASE_API_KEY: '1234'  FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: 'abc'
```

Or you can do it in Heroku Dashboard:

Have a look on [this Heroku web-page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) for both.